# How to add the "Please Wait" popup when submitting a form in magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I have an admin module in magento. When the form is submitted I want to be able to show the "Please Wait" popup (the same way you get one when making changes to the categories). I am not currently using any AJAX but assume I need to submit the form using ajax. I don't have any phtml files as my form information is set programmatically (as it's dynamic).

Can someone point me in the right direction to use the "Please Wait" in magento, either with or without AJAX?

If you need any more information about how I am displaying the form please let me know as I don't know what information is required and don't want to just fill my post with random snippets.

**Resolved**

Just for clarity to save going through comments:

I overrode the default save button to add a JS onclick:

```
$this->_updateButton('save', 'onclick', 'submitForm()');
```

I then included a JS file using `layout.xml`

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="addJs"><script>mymodule/javascript.js</script></action>
</reference>
```

Then added a JS function:

```
function submitForm(){
    $('edit_form').request({
         onComplete: function()  { 
             window.location.href = document.URL; 
         }
     })  
}
```

This sorted it for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default in magento admin, any ajax you submit with the code below will display 'please wait'

```
function submitForm(){
   new Ajax.Request(url, {
      method:'post',
      .....
   });
 }


$fieldset->addField('submit', 'submit', array(
      'label'     => Mage::helper('form')->__('Submit'),
      'required'  => true,
      'onclick' => "submitForm",
      'value'  => 'Submit()',
      'after_element_html' => '<small>Comments</small>',
      'tabindex' => 1
    ));
```

Take a look @

http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-admin-form-field

http://turnkeye.com/blog/magento-admin-form/

Comment: Wouldn't this have to be called via a `.phtml` file though? Could I force something by adding it to the `onClick` of my admin button?

Comment: You could add the above code to a `javascript.js` file and including it using layout.xml ... then programmatically add a button that trigger the code see http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/241624/#t342203

Comment: Thanks for that information. Are you saying I need to use a renderer for this? I'm struggling to see what I need to do with that example as that seems to be about drawing a button using html.

Comment: I would recommend using a .phtml, by copying the code to the generate above.. take a look at my update

Comment: The problem with using .phtml files is that I followed an example on excellencemagentoblog.com to do vertical tabs and I don't know how to translate that into a .phtml format (I am very new to Magento). I have added a button to the page and am triggering my Javascript function. How can I post the form within the `new Ajax.Request()` now? p.s I really appreciate your assistance.

Comment: OK I have it updating with the "Please Wait" by calling `$('edit_form').request();`. It looks like I just need to do a redirect after processing my code. Am I handling this in an arse about face way?

Comment: Get it to work first, you can always refactor your code later

Comment: Ok, sound advice. It's now working and I can still use the standard Magento message responses. This is the JS I ended up with: `function submitForm(){
   $('edit_form').request({
        onComplete: function()  { 
            window.location.href = document.URL; 
        }
    })  
 }` Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 13):

This is the most regularly found page for adding the please wait spinner, so I thought I'd increase the answers here for those of us who find this page where they want to display the spinner when not submitting via ajax, but doing some other js processing.

There's a very simple way to display the spinner (adminhtml template), that's by adding the following js to your page :-

```
Element.show('loading-mask');
/* do your js stuff here */
Element.hide('loading-mask');
```

Do bear in mind that any ajax that does get executed will hide your loading mask itself, so if calling a click on a button, you may want to re-show the mask again afterwards.